# Name a person who loves to do things manually

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What will you call a person who loves to do things manually rather than using any technology tools.

Comment: Do you have any more context to go a long with this? What kinds of things are they doing? Writing? Building furniture? Traveling? Also, are they anti-technologist? Are they just older and take too long to learn new things? Otherwise this question is too open ended.

Comment: This isn't directly related to them doing things by hand but the person is probably a [hipster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipster_(contemporary_subculture)).

Answer (score 5):

You could simply call such a person a *[traditionalist](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/american/traditionalist#traditionalist_4)*. I would say that they're *[old school](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20school)*.

Comment: By now, many things are not traditionally done by hand.

Comment: @einpoklum I suggest that you look up the actual meaning of [_traditional_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/traditional).

Comment: Traditions are not eternal, they also develop or fade over time.

Answer (score 3):

Literally, a '***hands-on***' person. More correctly,  a '***literally hands-on***' person.

Comment: This is not what the phrase "hands-on" means (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hands-on). I suppose you could use it this way, but you risk being misunderstood.

Comment: I know, which is the reason I said *literally*. And there need be no doubt people would misunderstand at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would say "Craftsman" or " Crafter" . "Luddite" sounds rather offensively and doesn´t convey the message of dexterity in his hands ...

Comment: Those work for jobs that involve something being created (e.g. Architect, Painter). But would they be suitable for other jobs, where nothing is actually being "crafted" (e.g. An accountant or administrator who prefers paper and pen to computers and calculators)?

Comment: well in this case I would say " manualist" even though the name refers more to a person using sign language , still it sounds ok to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the term "[maker](http://www.makershed.com/Default.asp)", but I'm not sure that's quite what you want.

Comment: That only works if they are "making" something.

Comment: Makers don't use machines or tools?

Comment: You're both correct - but I did say it's not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

*[Handcrafter](http://www.wordnik.com/words/handcrafter)* comes close. It means a person who does handicraft. It doesn't quite cover the person who avoids electric pencil sharpeners and uses grass shears to trim his lawn.

A *Luddite* is an anti-industrialist, and by extension a person who opposes advancements in mass production or opposes changes in technology. It is not so much a person who personally prefers to do all things manually.

*Craftsman* or *artisan* is a person who practises a skilled trade. The person's output is unlikely to be mass produced. But a craftsman or artisan might use advanced technology, or very little technology, or anything in between.

Answer (score 1):

We may perhaps call them a ***dinosaur***.

Wiktionary:

> *Noun*
>   **[dinosaur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dinosaur)** ‎(plural dinosaurs)
>
> **3** (*figuratively, colloquial*) **A person** or organisation **that** is very old, has very old-fashioned views, or **is not willing to change
>   and adapt**

Comment: [David Cameron used to always refer to Dennis Skinner](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-16622894)—the Labour MP in his 80s—as a dinosaur due to his age and supposedly old ideas, trying to allude to the definition given here.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call them a *hedonistic artisan* to reflect on their love of making things by hand.

Comment: However, if the question is referring to doing rather than making, you should consider _technophobe, retrophile_ or even a _nostalgist._

Answer (score 0):

I would probably call them a [luddite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite)

> "The Luddites were a social movement of 19th-century English textile
>   artisans who protested ... against the changes produced by the
>   Industrial Revolution"- Wikipedia

It's not terribly complimentary though, so it depends how you intend to mean it.

Comment: Luddite implies actively trying to sabotage use of mechanized means, or at least opposing it on principle. Not to mention the fact that whatever that person is doing by hand might itself involve technology, e.g. someone who assembles his car by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I might call him a **DIY** kind of a person (a **do-it-yourself** kind of a person, see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_it_yourself)), or say "he's into DIY".